# Is there any way to let a child process be listed under its parent process in Task Manager?

Tags: windows, winapi, treeview, createprocess, taskmanager

I'm using Windows 11.

Running processes are listed in the "Processes" tab in Task Manager.

They are expandable, and if I click on the `[>]` mark on the left side of a process's name, the tree will be expanded.

My application launches some child processes, by calling the Win32 `CreateProcess()` API.

Now, my application and child processes are listed as separate processes. I want to make the child processes be listed underneath my application in the tree. But I can't found the parameter to do that.

Is this possible with `CreateProcess()`, or another API? Or is it impossible?

Comment: It should be possible because some applications have implemented this such as chrome,  teams, etc. I'm going to consult.

Comment: Each process has a parent process (ID). While the parent process could be gone, the reference to its ID is still there (Search "Windows Parent Process ID"). Having that, you can build the hierarchy yourself.

Comment: This is not a feature you have to opt-in. You can verify this by launching a program that has been released prior to the introduction of process trees in Windows 8. Programs don't have to do anything special. All they have to do is *not* break the process tree built from the parent process ID. A common way to break the tree is by executing a transient launcher process. Once that terminates, its child processes no longer link back to a valid process ID.

Comment: The "Processes" tab does not display actual processes (that is done in the "Details" tab instead). It displays "Applications" instead. Application windows are grouped together if they share the same [Application User Model ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/appids), ie if a single process creates multiple windows that share the same ID, or multiple processes create their own windows that share the same ID.

Comment: Thanks for useful information, Seems what I want to do is possible with using AppUserModelID. I'll try it!